# Intermittent pixel format error when using fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm using the (excellent!) [node-fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) library as the first step in a video processing pipeline. Depending on the source video I provide to node-fluent-ffmpeg (videos are coming from same provider which makes this behavior surprising, but I digress), I sometimes see the following error when piping the output to the next ffmpeg processor in my pipeline:

> Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format

Per [this](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/724) issue I have tried setting `inputFormat('mp4')`, `videoCodec('libx264')` and `.inputOption('-pix_fmt yuv420p')`. The first two don't seem to have any effect and the third causes the following error: "Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Option pixel_format not found." (To complicate things, I'm running this process inside a Google Cloud Function, so I'm unclear how to query for which pix_fmts *are* available.)

Does anyone know how I can work around this issue?

Here's my latest attempt in full:

```
  const process = ffmpeg({source: stream})
    .inputFormat('mp4')
    .inputOption('-pix_fmt yuv420p')
    .setFfmpegPath(ffmpeg_static.path)
    .videoBitrate(1024)
    .videoCodec('libx264')
    .aspect('1:1')
    .format('mp4')
    .noAudio()
    .seekInput(start)
    .duration(duration)
    .save(destination);
```

I was able to query ffmpeg for the available pixel formats and, while yuv420p isn't available, a number of others are. The closest (textual) match is yuv4mpegpipe, but that results in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yuv4mpegpipe` is not a pixel format, Its an input/output format. The reason your code is not working is `-pix_fmt yuv420p` is an `outputOption` not an `inputOption`. It's probably best to not set `inputFormat` either, and let ffmpeg decide automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that I am able to set the pixel format using `outputOption`. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the overarching problem.

Comment: Sorry, What exactly is the overarching problem? `Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format` would seem to indicate a corrupted input. Can you post a sample?

Comment: Please don't be sorry, that was just me venting and you _did_ answer my original question. I was still seeing the pixel format error message after setting the pixel format, but that seems to have been solved by setting the `inputFormat('mp4')`.  It's very possible that the source is corrupt, I will investigate that tomorrow. In the meantime, here's an example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xb6t3qgei4jezuv/asset.1554264828558.mp4 Thanks, again, for your help!